# Large attachments error: Missing validated user from the ActiveMQ Artemis message

Tags: corda, activemq-artemis

The below error is thrown when trying to use large attachments (ex. 1GB).

I found [this related issue in Corda's Atlassian page](https://r3-cev.atlassian.net/browse/CORDA-2215). Has this been fixed in Corda 4 or are large attachments still not supported?

```
E 00:45:52+0000 [Thread-4 (ActiveMQ-client-global-threads)] core.client.run - AMQ214000: Failed to call onMessage {}
java.lang.IllegalArgumentException: Missing validated user from the Artemis message
at net.corda.node.services.messaging.RPCServer.actorFrom(RPCServer.kt:409) ~[corda-node-3.1-corda.jar:?]
at net.corda.node.services.messaging.RPCServer.context(RPCServer.kt:403) ~[corda-node-3.1-corda.jar:?]
at net.corda.node.services.messaging.RPCServer.clientArtemisMessageHandler(RPCServer.kt:315) ~[corda-node-3.1-corda.jar:?]
at net.corda.node.services.messaging.RPCServer.access$clientArtemisMessageHandler(RPCServer.kt:79) ~[corda-node-3.1-corda.jar:?]
at net.corda.node.services.messaging.RPCServer$createRpcConsumer$1.invoke(RPCServer.kt:196) ~[corda-node-3.1-corda.jar:?]
at net.corda.node.services.messaging.RPCServer$createRpcConsumer$1.invoke(RPCServer.kt:79) ~[corda-node-3.1-corda.jar:?]
at net.corda.node.services.messaging.RPCServerKt$sam$MessageHandler$5b9bfc45.onMessage(RPCServer.kt) ~[corda-node-3.1-corda.jar:?]
at org.apache.activemq.artemis.core.client.impl.ClientConsumerImpl.callOnMessage(ClientConsumerImpl.java:997) ~[artemis-core-client-2.2.0.jar:2.2.0]
at org.apache.activemq.artemis.core.client.impl.ClientConsumerImpl.access$400(ClientConsumerImpl.java:49) ~[artemis-core-client-2.2.0.jar:2.2.0]
at org.apache.activemq.artemis.core.client.impl.ClientConsumerImpl$Runner.run(ClientConsumerImpl.java:1120) [artemis-core-client-2.2.0.jar:2.2.0]
at org.apache.activemq.artemis.utils.actors.OrderedExecutor.doTask(OrderedExecutor.java:42) [artemis-commons-2.2.0.jar:2.2.0]
at org.apache.activemq.artemis.utils.actors.OrderedExecutor.doTask(OrderedExecutor.java:31) [artemis-commons-2.2.0.jar:2.2.0]
at org.apache.activemq.artemis.utils.actors.ProcessorBase$ExecutorTask.run(ProcessorBase.java:53) [artemis-commons-2.2.0.jar:2.2.0]
at java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor.runWorker(ThreadPoolExecutor.java:1149) [?:1.8.0_192]
at java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor$Worker.run(ThreadPoolExecutor.java:624) [?:1.8.0_192]
at java.lang.Thread.run(Thread.java:748) [?:1.8.0_192]
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Support for large attachments (100MBs+) would be added in Corda 5 as per following link -

https://r3-cev.atlassian.net/browse/CORDA-1826?focusedCommentId=49773&page=com.atlassian.jira.plugin.system.issuetabpanels%3Acomment-tabpanel